# if $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$ then $f$ is positive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> I am having these two results : 
>   Let $f \in C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ :
>
> (1) If $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) >0$ then there is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ on $]0, \epsilon[$
>
> (2) If $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f$ is positive there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f'$ is positive on $[0, \epsilon[$ and negative on $]1-\epsilon, 1]$

Note that these are assumptions so I am not sure both these results are true.

I think I might have a solution for $(1)$ using an aysmptics. Since $f$ is $C^1$ we have : $f(h) = f(0) + hf'(0) + o(h)$ in a neighboorhood of $0$. Thus $f(h) = hf'(0) + \epsilon(h)$ where $\epsilon$ is a continuous function which goes to $0$ when $h \to 0$.Yet since $hf'(0) = O(h)$ (since $f'(0) > 0)$ then $hf'(0) \geq \epsilon(h)$ for $h$ small enough. Hence there is an $\epsilon$ which veryfy the conditions of $(1)$ Is it correct ? 
If it's correct I am really interested in an other way of proving this result.

Moreover I don't at all how to proceed for $(2)$.

Thank you.

Comment: What has this to do with `sequences-and-series`, with `ordinary-differential-equation` or with `pde`?

Comment: In (2) what do you mean by "$f$ is positive"? Do you mean that $f$ is postive in the interval $]0,1[$?

Comment: @bonjoufhaji, did you mean that $f$ is *nonnegative* (not strictly positive) on $[0, 1]$?  Because it is zero at $x=0$ and at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would address (1) by contradiction.  Suppose: for every $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, there exists an $h$ such that $0 < h < \epsilon$ and $f(h) < 0$.  It follows that there exists a monotonically decreasing sequence $h_{n}$ of strictly positive terms that converges to $0$.

For every $h_{n}$, we have:
$$
{f(0 + h_{n}) - f(0) \over h_{n}} = {f(h_{n}) \over h_{n}} < 0.
$$
By taking the limit of this as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain $f'(0)$, which therefore must be nonpositive:
$$
f'(0) \leq 0.
$$
This contradicts the assumption that $f'(0) > 0$.

Comment: If you do a proof by contradiction it means there is a sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $0$ such that $f(x_n) < 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you @Thinking.  I felt something was amiss.  Will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

(2) is false. Consider
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2(2+\sin\frac1x)(1-x)&x>0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: If we make the further assumption that $f$ is $C^2$ $(2)$ should work no ?

Comment: @Thinking, even for $f$ in ${\cal C}^{\infty}$, (2) generally fails.  Consider
$$
f(x) = \sin^2(2 \pi x) - 10^{-10} x(x - 1).
$$