# $f \in C^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ then $f' \geq 0$ on [0, \epsilon[ and $f' \leq 0$ on $]1-\epsilon, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $f \in C^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f$ is positive on $[0,1]$ then is it true that  $f' \geq 0$ on $[0, \epsilon[$ and $f' \leq 0$ on $]1-\epsilon, 1]$ ?

A [counter-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144386/if-f0-0-and-f0-1-then-f-is-positive?noredirect=1#comment6477511_3144386) has been given in the case where $f$ is only $C^1$. Yet I feel like when $f$ is $C^2$ it might true since when we study the differential equation $x'' + px = 0$ where $p$ is a continuous function then a solution of this differential equation which has two consecutive $0$ seems to verify the above property.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of something kind of like $\sin$ but squished between the lines $y=0$ and $y=x$? Oscillations are usually the first thing you should try when trying to test local conditions on derivatives.

Comment: Tweeking $x^2(\sin x+1)$ should work

Comment: The counter-example you mention does not seem to be adequate. I don't think that the function displayed there is $C^1([0,1])$. It is however $C^0$.

Comment: In fact, $x^{(2+\epsilon)}(1+\sin(1/x))/(1+\sin 1)$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the $C^\infty$ function
$$
f(x)=e^{-\tfrac{1}{x(1-x)}}\Bigl(2+\sin\frac1{x(1-x)}\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Ok, great it completely solve my question then. Thank you.